# Getting binary labels on from a dataframe and a list of labels

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following list of labels,

```
labs = ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6','G7']
```

and also suppose that I have the following df:

```
   group entity_label
0      0           G1
1      0           G2
3      1           G5
4      1           G1
5      2           G1
6      2           G2
7      2           G3
```

to produce the above df you can use:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame({'group': [0,0,0,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'entity_label':['G1','G2','G2','G5','G1','G1','G2','G3','G3']})

df_test.drop_duplicates(subset=['group','entity_label'], keep='first')
```

for each group I want to use a mapping to look up on the labels and make a new dataframe with binary labels

```
   group    entity_label_binary
0      0  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1      1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2      2  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

namely for group 0 we have G1 and G2 hence 1s in above table and so on. I wonder how one can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option, based on [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html):

```
labs = ['G1','G2','G3','G4','G5','G6','G7']

(pd.crosstab(df_test['group'], df_test['entity_label'])
   .clip(upper=1)
   .reindex(columns=labs, fill_value=0)
   .agg(list, axis=1)
   .reset_index(name='entity_label_binary')
)
```

Variant, with [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) and [`groupby.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.max.html):

```
(pd.get_dummies(df_test['entity_label'])
   .groupby(df_test['group']).max()
   .reindex(columns=labs, fill_value=0)
   .agg(list, axis=1)
   .reset_index(name='entity_label_binary')
)
```

Output:

```
   group    entity_label_binary
0      0  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
1      1  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
2      2  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you but this is producing labels of length 5 while in my question labels are length 7 acording to len(labs). Also in really labels can have various names so would wonder if we can do it without using f'G{x+1}'

Comment: @Wiliam I just changed it, the logic is the same, just pass the labels you want ;)